# laravel8 storing ids from controller

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to extract id(as primary key) from following dd($cv)

[image]

and then make it equal to CV_id in order to stroe it in DB table   :
This is storing method that I used in controller :

```
    public function appl(Request $request)
    { 
      
        $application = new JobApplication;
        $jobs = Job::find($request->job_id)->get();
        $application->job_id =$request->job_id;

    
          $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
         $application->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

 
 

         $cv = auth()->user()->cv->get('id');
         dd( $cv);

         $application->cv_id = auth()->user()->id;
        
        $application->save();
        
 





    
}
```

So the question is how to extract only id from that user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just user like a normal model and get id from it.

```
     dd( $cv->id);
     dd( $cv->user_id);
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

Please use this as follows.

```
$result_id=$cv[0]['id'];
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it